# Photoshop Script to Randomly Select Images

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to use Javascript to select two random images from a local folder and place on separate Photoshop layers. I have created an array with the filepaths to choose from.

```
#target photoshop
var allImages = [“file path/img-1.jpg”, "file path/img-2.jpg", "file path/img-3.jpg"];
//this is a large array of file paths to 100 different images
var pickImage = allImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
allImages.length)];
var imgFile = File(pickImage);
var openFile = app.open(imgFile);
var secondImage = allImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length)];
app.activeDocument.artLayers.add(secondImage);
```

This opens the first image and creates a blank layer above but does not insert the second image. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you must first create a file object before you may open an image. All you have to do is create the variable and then point it at secondImage. Just like you did with the first image:

```
var imgFile = File(pickImage);
```

In your current approach, your easiest solution would probably be to just make a variable secondPickedImage and assign it to the same thing as pickImage. Although, this leaves the possibility of you picking the same image, you could fix that with an if statement.
   I would recommend changing your approach and turning pickImage into a function that you can call that will return a random number for your array - saves space, and cleans up your code. Then put the secondImage assignment in a do while loop that keeps picking a random number until you pick a number different from the pickImage number so your first and second pictures are different.

Source: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide.pdf  page 29.